# Drawing a Template Class in UML

Tags: c++, templates, uml, visio, template-classes

I have a problem drawing a template class diagram in UML.

I know that in UML a template class should have a small rectangle in the up right corner of the class but the problem is how do i draw that ?
Is there any special option called template class or do i have to draw it manually ?

By the way am using Visio 2013 to the draw the class.

Comment: It totally depends, what your tool is capable of. Did you check the visio UML reference? IIRC visio isn't very good at UML models. I'd recommend some decent UML tool like Sparx Enterprise Architect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is related to the capabalities of your tool. Please find [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UML_tools) a list of UML tools.
I am sure that  Entreprise Architect, MagicDraw, Modelio, Papyrus, Rhapsody, Rationals are able to do what you need.

Comment: Note : Modelio and Papyrus are free while Enterprise Architect (Sparx Systems), MagicDraw (Dassault), Rhapsody (IBM), Rationals (IBM) are not.